# consultas de Pivot Tables en Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, label

Estoy iniciando el manejo de datos en JupyterLab, y tengo el siguiente caso con mi código:

```
A_imp= df.pivot_table(index= ("num_mes", "clasificacion"), columns="año",values="pzas_recibidas/1000", aggfunc="sum")
A_impt= df.pivot_table(index= ("año", "clasificacion"), columns="num_mes",values="pzas_recibidas/1000", aggfunc="sum")
Imp=A_imp.query('clasificacion == ["IMPCATMex"]')


colores = ['#FF1493', '#6495ED','#483D8B']
Imp.plot(kind ='bar', width=0.8,figsize=(20,10), color=colores)
A_impt.query('clasificacion == ["IMPCATMex"]')
```

Ese código me arroja la tabla que quiero con la gráfica pero los titulos no los he podido cambiar, como hago para que los valores en el eje x digan los meses del año algo como: xlabetick=['enero', 'febrero', .... etc]

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay veces que lo más fácil es combinar lo que utiliza `pandas` con `matplotlib`, en este caso, el método `plot` de `pandas` devuelve un [`matplotlib.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html)  (Recuerda que `pandas` utiliza `matplotlib` internamente) y por lo tanto puedes utilizar [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) para configurar las etiquetas de los ejes.

**Nota:** Como no agregaste tus datos hice un `dataframe` genérico con los siguientes datos (Archivo "sample2.csv")

```
            Col1    Col2
fecha       
2022-01-01  12      1
2022-02-01  11      2
2022-03-01  10      3
2022-04-01  9       4
2022-05-01  8       5
2022-06-01  7       6
2022-07-01  6       7
2022-08-01  5       8
2022-09-01  4       9
2022-10-01  3       10
2022-11-01  2       11
2022-12-01  1       12
```

Lo único que hay que hacer es asignar tu gráfica a una variable, por ejemplo `ax` y luego asignar las etiquetas en esa variable

```
ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', index_col=['fecha'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
colores = ['#FF1493', '#6495ED']
ax = df.plot(kind ='bar', width=0.8,figsize=(20,10), color=colores)
meses = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre']
ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciono perfecto! que pasa si ahora también quiero ver los meses como títulos de la tabla que se ve al principio? es decir que en vez de 1, 2, 3 aparezca el mes, tengo una columna "mes" pero al colocarla lo arregla por órden alfabetico.

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!